# MySql stops writing, but keeps reading

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a magento store running on Debian, with LAMP, the server is a VPN with 1GB RAM, 1 Core Processor.
MySQL randomly but often stops writing new data to tables, magento doesn't show any error, says that it successfully saved the data. It can read the tables without problem, the website keeps running okay, it just doesn't save any new data.
If I restart MySQL it starts saving new data again, then randomly (I think, couldn't relate it to any action) stops writing some time later, it can be days or hours. 
I've turned on query log, but not sure what to look for on it, 
I found this common error after mysql stops writing: INSERT INTO index_process_event (process_id,event_id,status) VALUES ('7', '10453', 'error') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = VALUES(status);
I've tried to reindex the whole process table as suggested by Henry, but no success.
After reindexing the event_id changed.

I don't believe the problem is low RAM, the website only get around 200 sessions/day, hardly more than 2 users online at the same time.

Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

try to see if there is any space left on your storage.

also try to see in system log in addition of mysql log.
grep / find for any line that have "error" string.

Comment: I have storage, I've only used 36% of the server HD. I'll have to wait until it happens again and then check the log, then I post the results. Thanks man.

Comment: So, after these days of log, I found this common error after mysql stops writing: INSERT INTO `index_process_event` (`process_id`,`event_id`,`status`) VALUES ('7', '10453', 'error') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = VALUES(`status`); I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Try to make the magento store page offline first, then reindex thermal whole index process table. This must be done via reinforcing to use magento internal function but via php code. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3160/magento-index-process-tables-cleanup